# hardware cuda decoding error

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding, cuvid

Please see my input udp stream information:

> ffprobe udp://IP:PORT

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://IP:PORT':
  Duration: N/A, start: 29796.225911, bitrate: N/A
  Program 16
    Stream #0:3[0x641]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:5[0x642](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 39
    Stream #0:7[0xf3d]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:8[0xf3e](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 11
    Stream #0:2[0x13ed]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0x13ee](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 3
    Stream #0:9[0x10ce]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:4[0x10cf](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1006]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1007](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
```

I want to decode the video stream (Stream #0:0[0x1006]) with Program id 1 
 And doing it with the following command:

> ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2G -probesize 11M -y -hwaccel cuvid -c:v
>   h264_cuvid -i udp://IP:PORT -map
>   0:#0x1006 -f rawvideo cuda_decoded.yuv

Please see the log:

```
[mpegts @ 0x2351d60] decoding for stream 0 failed
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://IP:PORT':
  Duration: N/A, start: 30271.455156, bitrate: N/A
  Program 16
    Stream #0:5[0x641]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:6[0x642](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 39
    Stream #0:2[0xf3d]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:4[0xf3e](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 11
    Stream #0:3[0x13ed]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:8[0x13ee](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 3
    Stream #0:7[0x10ce]: Video: h264 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 26.17 fps, 2.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:9[0x10cf](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 96 kb/s
  Program 1
    Stream #0:0[0x1006]: Video: h264 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 16x32, 2.08 fps, 2.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 2514.04 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1007](eng): Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
[h264_cuvid @ 0x240ca20] ctx->cvdl->cuvidCreateDecoder(&cudec, &cuinfo) failed -> CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE: invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> rawvideo (native))
Error while opening decoder for input stream #0:0 : Generic error in an external library
```

Also I can decode it without any problems with the next command:

> ffmpeg -analyzeduration 2G -probesize 11M -y -i udp://IP:PORT -map
>   0:#0x1006 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p software_decoded.yuv

**This issue affects only for some input streams.**

Have you any ideas why this issue occurs and any recommendations how to fix it?

Comment: Try removing the `-hwaccel cuvid` and comment back if that works (for now, as a test)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream 0 is `Stream #0:0[0x1006]: Video: mpeg2video` for which you need `-c:v mpeg2_cuvid`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in ffmpeg. When you explicitly specify a type of the HW acceleration (i.e. cuvid), ffmpeg assigns 0 to `CUVIDDECODECREATEINFO::ulNumDecodeSurfaces` and to `CUVIDDECODECREATEINFO::ulNumOutputSurfaces`. Consequently, a call to cuvidCreateDecoder fails, since NVDEC doesn't have surfaces to output decoded pictures.